# Can't do a post scenario with gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to get familiar with Gatling but i have a problem with the post scenario. I'm using their api, so i tried to add a computer, here is my scenario :

```
var httpProtocol = http.baseUrl("http://computer-database.gatling.io")

    var scenarioBuilder = scenario("Adding Computer")
      .exec(
        http("Adding a Computer")
          .post("/computers/new")
          .formParam("name","HP")
          .formParam("introduced","2019-01-01")
          .formParam("discontinued","2019-02-02")
          .formParam("company","Sony")
      )

    setUp(
      scenarioBuilder.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
        .protocols(httpProtocol)
    )
```

When i execute the test, i get a 400 error, but i don't know how can i fix it, i already checked the parameters and it looks good.

EDIT :

Just saw that i must use formParamMap when i have more than one form parameter, but still the same issue, always error 400

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The correct url for posting on this app is `/computers`, not `/computers/new`.
2. The company parameter is an int id, not the String label

Comment: Thank you, the problem was the company parameter, you are right, it's an int not a string. Thanks a lot !!